# error while installling qt mobility tool kit

Tags: alsa, qt

I am installing qt mobility tool kit but it shows an error message :

> 1.2.0/src/multimedia' make[2]: Warning: File Makefile' has modification time 1.1e+04 s in the future g++ -c -pipe -g
>   -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_SHARED -DQTM_PLUGIN_PATH=\"/home/aboobacker/Desktop/qt-mobility-opensource-src-1.2.0/install/plugins\"
>   -DQT_MAKEDLL -DQT_BUILD_MULTIMEDIA_LIB -DHAS_ALSA -DQT_MULTIMEDIA_QMEDIAPLAYER -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL -I/usr/include/qt4 -I../global -I. -Iaudio -Ivideo -Ieffects -I/usr/X11R6/include -I../../build/Debug/QtMultimediaKit/moc -o ../../build/Debug/QtMultimediaKit/qaudiodevicefactory.o
>   audio/qaudiodevicefactory.cpp In file included from
>   audio/qaudiodevicefactory.cpp:60:0:
>   audio/qaudiodeviceinfo_alsa_p.h:57:28: fatal error: alsa/asoundlib.h:
>   No such file or directory compilation terminated. make[2]: ***
>   [../../build/Debug/QtMultimediaKit/qaudiodevicefactory.o] Error 1
>   make[2]: Leaving
>   directory/home/aboobacker/Desktop/qt-mobility-opensource-src-1.2.0/src/multimedia'
>   make[1]: * [sub-multimedia-make_default] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving
>   directory
>   `/home/aboobacker/Desktop/qt-mobility-opensource-src-1.2.0/src' make:
>   * [sub-src-make_default-ordered] Error 2 aboobacker@aboobacker-desktop:~/Desktop/qt-mobility-opensource-src-1.2.0$

How to solve this?

Answer (score 11):

To compile packages you need to install the dependencies, including the headers, or -dev packages. Try

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev
```

Check the dependencies listed in any README included with the source code (more likely then not you will have more dependencies to install).

Comment: linux/qsysteminfo_linux_common.cpp:78:35: fatal error: X11/extensions/Xrandr.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
this is the next error how to fix this?

Comment: When compiling from source, you need to install all the dependencies first. The dependencies are usually listed in the README file, and you also need the dependency-dev package, as with libasound2-dev.

Comment: sorry readme file does not include dependencies

Comment: cd /tmp/%DISTNAME%
 ./configure -prefix $TARGET_DIR

Comment: make
To install the libraries and tools to $TARGET_DIR, type:

 make install
If you have specified an install directory with root ownership, you will need to type:

 su -c "make install"
     or
 sudo make install